# Server error with unsupported URL

Tags: node.js, angular

To delete an item from a list, here is my client code:

```
deleteResource(resType: String, patientId: String): Observable<IFhirAck> {
        console.log("DeleteResource");
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        headers.append("Accept", "application/json");
        headers.append("USER_KEY", "cGgwGRCzdGXGMtV7WjcW"); //TOUCHSTONE KEY
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        return this.http.delete(this.baseUrl + resType + "/id/" + patientId, options)
            .map((res: Response) => res.json())
            .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error from Observable http.put call')) 
    }
```

The logic reached the server and the server throws the error as

> Unsupported URL: [/Patient/id/8bb3163e-4f2f-4c31-8c14-0afc3d0a7842]

The value after id is correct as shown in mongodb. What could be the cause for "unsupported URL"? How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the server side missed "/id" in the router module.